# How to select the first two row of each group and count difference between them in one column?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.1

I have table like that

```
ID_WE   ID_B    ID_WO   RDATA   RSIZE
11111   22      1   1998-10-01  14
11111   22      2   1998-09-30  17
11111   23      1   1998-10-01  23
11112   22      1   1998-09-30  14
```

`ID_WE`, `ID_B` and `ID_WO` together are primary key. For every combination  id-we, id_b there are few `ID_WO`. Every `ID_WO` have a lot of reads, information about reads are in `RDATA` and `RSIZE`

I need to fetch  table like that

```
ID_WE   ID_B    ID_WO   DAYS    DIF
11111   22      1       1       0
```

`DIF` is difference in `RSIZE` between two last reads for given `ID_WO`,
`DAYS` is how many days have passed between two last reads

It probably need some group by and maybe max(rdata) to get the that to count difference in days and size. I'm really lost how to get result like that. I will appreciate any tips how to get required results.

Comment: ID_WE and ID_B together can't be the primary key since there are such duplicates.

Comment: Which Firebird version? With Firebird 3 it is probably easier to do than with earlier versions. BTW: I don't understand given the sample data, why `DAYS` would have a value 780 and and `DIF` a value of 6.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel-  Fierbird 2.1 , and you're right it should be 1 day and 0 dif

Comment: @jarlh  my misteak it should by  ID_WE and ID_B and ID_WO are primary key

Comment: So ... as ID_WO _increases_ for a given ID_WE+ID_B, the RDATA date _decreases_?  In your data, 11111-22-1 was read on October 1st, 1998, but 11111-22-2 was read on September 30th, 1998?  Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for comments and answers, that have got me on right track of thinking. I finally have figure it out. With help from [this page](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) on Baron Schwartz's Blog (it's usefull resource if someone need to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL).

I get the bigest and seconde bigest `RDATA` and add to data coresponding `RSIZE` in query like that, biggest(FOO):

```
select oo.id_wej,oo.id_ob,oo.id_wo, oo.odata,oo.od
from (select id_wej,id_ob,id_wo,odata from odczyty
where odata = (select max(odata) from odczyty o where o.id_wej=odczyty.id_wej and o.id_ob=odczyty.id_ob and o.id_wo=odczyty.id_wo)) as x
inner join odczyty oo on oo.id_wej=x.id_wej and oo.id_ob=x.id_ob and oo.id_wo=x.id_wo and oo.odata=x.odata
order by id_wej,id_ob,id_wo)as ok
on od.id_wej=ok.id_wej and od.id_ob=ok.id_ob and od.id_wo=ok.id_wo
```

and second biggest(BAR):

```
select o.id_we,o.id_b,o.id_wo, o.rdata,o.rsize
from (select id_we,id_b,id_wo,rdata from odczyty
where rdata =(select max(rdata)
from odczyty o2
where o2.id_we=odczyty.id_we and o2.id_b=odczyty.id_b
and o2.id_wo=odczyty.id_wo and
rdata <(select max(rdata) from odczyty o3
where o3.id_we=o2.id_we and
o3.id_b=o2.id_b and o3.id_wo=o2.id_wo))) as x
inner join odczyty o on o.id_we=x.id_we and o.id_b=x.id_b and o.id_wo=x.id_wo and o.rdata=x.rdata
```

Using this two queries i made this :

```
   select od.id_wej,od.id_ob,od.id_wo, ok.odata-od.odata as days,ok.od-od.od as dif
from(BAR)as od  inner join
(FOO)as ok
on od.id_wej=ok.id_wej and od.id_ob=ok.id_ob and od.id_wo=ok.id_wo
order by id_wej, id_ob, id_wo
```

I replaced inserted queries with FOO and BAR for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT MIN(ID_WE) ID_WE,ID_B,ID_WO,DAYS,DIF
FROM
(
     SELECT MIN(ID_WE) ID_WE,MIN(ID_B) ID_B,MIN(ID_WO) ID_WO, 
            MAX(RDATA)-Min(RDATA) DAYS,MAX(RSIZE)-Min(RSIZE) DIF   
     FROM TABLE1
     GROUP BY ID_WE,ID_B
)AS G
GROUP BY ID_WE
```

Comment: Close but  MAX(RDATA)-Min(RDATA)DAYS give my difference between first and last , and i need last two . More like MAX(RDATA)-MAX2(RDATA)DAYS.Where max2 is second largest .

Comment: Can you post the query in SQL Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Instead of TABLE1 i have build in something getting the two last elements:

```
SELECT MIN(ID_WE) ID_WE,ID_B,ID_WO,DAYS,DIF
FROM
 (
 SELECT MIN(d.ID_WE) ID_WE,MIN(d.ID_B) ID_B,MIN(d.ID_WO) ID_WO, 
        MAX(d.rdata)-Min(d.rdata) DAYS,MAX(d.RSIZE)-Min(d.RSIZE) DIF   
 FROM 
     (  select t.id_we, t.id_b, t.id_wo, t.max from 
       (( select b.id_we, b.id_b, b.id_wo, max(b.rdata) as max
            from test b
            where b.rdata NOT IN
                (select max(a.rdata)
                from test a
                group by a.id_we, a.id_b, a.id_wo
                )
            group by b.id_we, b.id_b, b.id_wo
        ) union
        (
          select e.id_we, e.id_b, e.id_wo, max(e.rdata)
          from test e
          group by e.id_we, e.id_b, e.id_wo
        )  
       ) t

        ) t4
        join test d on t4.id_we = d.id_we and d.id_b = t4.id_b and d.id_wo = t4.id_wo and d.rdata = t4.max
   GROUP BY t4.ID_WE,t4.ID_B
)AS G
GROUP BY ID_WE;
```